# what does the meaning of the dotted line in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

what does the meaning of the dotted line in IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You really should provide more context in your questions.

IntelliJ IDEA follows the UML conventions in showing relationships between the classes. see [IntelliJ class-diagram](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html#analyze_class)
UML conventions see [wikipedia Class_diagram#Relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Relationships)